# Keyboard shortcut to navigate through screens in VS project properties?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Once in the project properties dialog, there are a vertical listing of tabs on the left hand side (Application, Build, Build Events, etc).  Is there any known keyboard shortcut that will cycle through them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>

Comment: This should be marked as "answered" ... this solution works perfectly.

Comment: Seconded ... and great tip, I've always wondered how to switch